# React Google Login Inline Styling

Tags: reactjs

I'm using google-login package. I've tried to update the background image and dimension of the button, it doesn't seem to work or Am i doing it wrong? I can't find any examples in the docs on how to implement inline styling. I just read that it is an object, here is my code.

```
 <GoogleLogin
    className="rounded-circle"
    icon={false}
    clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}
    buttonText=""
    onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
    onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
    style={{  backgroundImage:url(${val.image.url}),
       width:50,
       height:50  
   }}
 />
```

[Plugin](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login) Any help on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems not possible, you can use custom render method.

```
 <GoogleLogin
    clientId="658977310896-knrl3gka66fldh83dao2rhgbblmd4un9.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    render={renderProps => (
      <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} style={customStyle}>This is my custom Google button</button>
    )}
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}
    onFailure={responseGoogle}
/>
```

You can check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-no9hdz?file=index.js), css rules coming from external css files are ignored.You can read it [here](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/src/google-login.js#L193) and [here](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/pull/180)

or you can use alternative plug-in : [react-google-button](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-google-button)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can combine both [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) and [react-google-button](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-google-button) :

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
import GoogleButton from 'react-google-button'

ReactDOM.render(
  <GoogleLogin
    clientId="your-google-app-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    render={renderProps => (
      <GoogleButton onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled}>Sign in with Google</GoogleButton>
    )}
    onSuccess={responseGoogleSuccess}
    onFailure={responseGoogleFailure}
    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
  />,
  document.getElementById('googleButton')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";    
import "./Login.scss";    
import axios from "axios";    
import { useGoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";   

const Login = () => {

 const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
           onSuccess: (codeResponse) => {
              axios.get(
                  `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo? 
                   access_token=${codeResponse.access_token}`,
                   {
                       headers: {
                       Authorization: `Bearer 
                       ${codeResponse.access_token}`,
                       Accept: "application/json",
                    },
            }).then((res) => {
                //  googleID, gmail, name, etc...
                console.log(res.data);
            }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
          },
         onError: (error) => console.log("Login Failed:", error),
      });

  return (

      <button className="google_sign" onClick={() => 
          googleLogin()}>
          <img src={require("../../assets/img/google- 
          logo.svg").default} alt="" />
          Sign In with Google
      </button>

  );
 };

 export default Login;
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPf3a.png)